# The tangent to graph of $y=\cos(x)$ is drawn at $x=\frac\pi6$. This tangent intersects graph of $y=\cos(x)$ again at $x=k$. Determine value of $k$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area, curves, tangent-line

> The tangent to the graph of $y=\cos(x)$ is drawn at $x=\frac\pi6$.
> This tangent intersects the graph of $y=\cos(x)$ again at $x=k$.

a. Determine the equation of the tangent at $x=\frac \pi6$.

b. Determine the value of $k$, correct to three decimal places.

c. Write an expression for the area enclosed between the tangent at $x=\frac\pi6$ and the curve $y=\cos(x)$.

d.  Hence evaluate the area correct to two decimal places.

I could solve part a.  The equation of the tangent at $x=\frac\pi6$ is:
$$y= -\frac{x}{2} + \frac {\sqrt 3}{2} + \frac{\pi}{12}$$

I am stuck at part b. We need to find where the tangent cuts the $y=\cos(x)$ curve at another point. I could find a graphical solution from Desmos but I need the analytical solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We expect users to add some attempts they have made along with the question, as this is not a homework site. It helps us help you :)

Comment: I could do till part (a). I found the equation of the tangent.
I'm stuck at part (b). Can someone help to solve part(b)?

Comment: Alright, please edit the question to add the equation of the tangent, and exactly at which point you are stuck

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks, Taussig for editing and improving the format of mathematical expressions in my question. I find it difficult to learn the coding for writing the formulas.

Comment: Wolfram gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29%3D-0.5*x%2Bsqrt%283%29%2F2%2Bpi%2F12) numerical solution 3.8168..., but I don't know by what method, may be a Newton algorithm

Comment: You could apply  [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to the function $f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{12}$, it would take some calculations though, on the other hand it's a good exercise

Comment: Sorry, an error in sign $f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\pi}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

The intuition behind the Newton algorithm is that if You want to solve an equation
$f(x)=0$ for a real valued differentiable function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where in our case $D=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\pi}{12}$ and You guessed a zero $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then the zero of the tangent in $(x_0,f(x_0))$, that is where the tangent intersects the $x$-axis, is even closer to the real zero, since the tangent is a local approximation of the function $f$. This zero is easily computed to be:
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}.$$
Now this can be iterated of course.

After trying to do this by hand and noticing I made a mistake I wrote a Python code:

```
import math
def f(x):   
    return math.cos(x)+0.5*x-0.5*math.sqrt(3)-math.pi/12    
def derivative_f(x):   
    return -math.sin(x)+0.5
x=math.pi+math.pi/6
n=1
while n<6:
    x=x-f(x)/derivative_f(x)  
    n=n+1
    print(x)
```

Sorry for the sloppy presentation, which isn't sloppy anymore thanks to Trebor. However the output is:
$$3.826445909962073$$
$$3.816833801086834$$
$$3.816801916445538$$
$$3.816801916092871$$
$$3.816801916092871$$
There is no change for further iterations in the first fifteen decimal places. It is certainly possible to do these five iterations by hand, just after two You are already correct to three decimal places. I chose as a starting value $x_0=\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks a lot for the edit! That was the first time I presented a code at MSE and it looked quite ugly. Thanks to You it looks fine now!

Comment: @Trebor the above comment was of course addressed to you, sorry for interchanging "b"for "v"